# Unevenly stretched sequences with LSTM/GRU

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, rnn, lstm

I am looking for a right NN architecture(probably, based on LSTM/GRU) for the classification problem I faced. I have an alphabet of events {A, B, C, D, ..., N} and sequences of these events for each training example. It is obviously that Embedding + LSTM/GRU gives me some baseline model, but my problem is a little bit more complex.

I also have timestamps attached to each event, so the same sequence in terms of order my represent different scenarios in reality for example {B, C, C,  <2 days after> A } and {B, <2 days after> C, C, A }. I tried to replace embedded vectors representing events with just events' timestamps(or duration from previous event) in the LSTM/GRU layer input and it gave me also some model with 75%-80% quality from the baseline model(and about ~6% of examples were correctly classified which were not correctly classified in baseline model). Now I am looking for an NN architecture to combine these two datasets(sequence of events and sequence of timestamps). I have already tried the following approaches:

1. Simply concatenate timestamp information into embedding vectors(with
   and without training), for example if embedding size = 32, we would
   have 33 dimensional vector for LSTM input - 97%-100% quality from
   the baseline model
2. NN with 2 inputs for event sequence and for
   timestamps sequence with concatenation before LSTM - ~90% quality
   from the baseline model
3. NN with 2 inputs for event sequence and for
   timestamp sequence with 2 LSTMs and concatenation after - ~95%
   quality from the baseline model

Thanks for any comments or recommendations.

Comment: Welcome to Data Science.SE!  It sounds like you've already figured out the solution (your option 1).  I'm not sure what "97%-100% quality" means (what's your definition of quality?), but if quality = accuracy, that sounds like a great solution.  What more is there to say?  I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting.  For that matters, what exactly is your question?  P.S. I'm assuming you've tried both the variant with the raw timestamp and the variant where you use the duration from the previous event.  If not, try that.

Comment: "97%-100% quality" means that this model is roughly the same as my baseline model,  for example if my metric is accuracy and an accuracy of the baseline model is 87%,  this solution gives a model with accuracy 85%-87%. So as I mentioned none of the approaches improved my quality,  that's why I am looking for a better option. I am not providing information about my metrics or a type of the problem,  because I am looking for general idea how to combine such kind of data.

Comment: OK.  Can you edit the question to clarify that, and to articulate a specific question?  We want all information in the question, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Separately: Perhaps the time doesn't really add any information.  Do you have any basis for the belief that taking into account the time information should lead to better accuracy?  What can you say about the random process that generated the data?  Do you have any hypotheses about its structure or how the passage of time might affect the class?